# Go: multiple variable short declaration statement with a multiple-return value function

Tags: go, variable-assignment, shorthand, multiple-variable-return

Is it possible to declare multiple variables at once with a multiple return value function call?

I want to use it in [*for* loop multiple variable initialization statement](https://github.com/szabgab/slides/blob/main/golang/examples/loop-on-two/loop_on_two.go) but can't find a way to do this in Go.

For example, this code snippet work:

```
x := "foo"
y, z := fmt.Print("bar")
```

However, when I try to use short declaration syntax `x, y := "value1", "value2"` it fails:

```
x, y, z := "foo", fmt.Print("bar")
```

As I understood, the compiler tries to assign both return values of a function to the second variable *y*.

Please advise is this a possible case in Golang, or what alternatives I can use in *for* loop initialization statement.

Comment: Your example is failing because fmt.Print() returns two values and you're combining it with single value assignment — not because you can't assign two strings in one line. x, y := 1, 2 does actually work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Please advise is this a possible case in Golang

No, it's not possible.

---

As per the official language spec, it is not allowed to combine multi-valued expressions with other multi-or-single-valued expressions in an assignment. The section on [Assignment Statements](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignment_statements) says:

> There are **two forms**. In the first, the right hand operand is a **single multi-valued expression** such as a function call ...  In the second form, the number of operands on the left must equal the number of expressions on the right, **each of which MUST be single-valued**.

And [short variable declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) is a shorthand of regular [variable declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) which follows the rules of assignment statements quoted above.

---

> what alternatives I can use in `for` loop initialization statement.

You could wrap the two statements into a custom function that returns 3 values and use that function in the `for` loop's `InitStmt`. For example:

```golang
func f() (string, int, error) {
    x := "foo"
    y, z := fmt.Print("bar")
    return x, y, z
}

for x, y, z := f(); ... {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on the documentation, `fmt.Print` is returning 2 values. So, you can't assign something like that.

The following is the documentation
[image]

The following one work because you are assigning 2 values return from fmt.Print.

```
x := "foo"
y, z := fmt.Print("bar")
```